# Can I merge Django local flavor add on fields?

Tags: django

Django has great fields under the local flavors package for specific local form fields like state and postal code.  However, I need to merge two or more of them together(e.g. merge Canadian provinces and American states into one field, or have Canadian and American postal/zip codes validate on the same field) or some how instantiate form object fields based on what country a user selects.  Does anyone have any experience with this same problem?  What solution did you use?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a drop down list, for instance:

```
<h3>Select Country:</h3>
<select>
    <option>America</option>
    <option>Canada</option>
</select>

<h3>Select Province/State:</h3>
<select>
</select>
```

The province/state list will then be automatically populated with states if America is selected or provinces if Canada is selected.  You could have a Country table:

```
Country
-------
America
Canada
```

A province/state table:

```
ProvSate
-------
(California, foreign key to Country)
(Ontario, foreign key to Country)
```

The above is a rough idea on how to solve that kind of problem.  There's not much validation in the above since choosing the appropriate countries will generate the corresponding prov/states.  If the country has no state or prov, return an empty drop down list for prov/state.